# eclipse debugger popup "are you sure you want to leave this page? "

Tags: php, eclipse

I just install PHP Eclipse IDE (4.5.1 Mars)

When I run the debugger the php is stuck because the internal browser (ie) pops up a message "are you sure you want to leave this page?"
but the popup is in the background.

thus I have to minimize all windows, maximize eclipse, minimize eclipse, and close the popup.

This is VERY annoying

how can I prevent this?

there is no browser open in eclipse, and it happens when it reaches a break point.

Can someone recommend a better IDE for PHP that has a debugger?

This doesn't happen on older eclipse version, but they have their own long bug list.

Comment: Your question is likely to get closed for being off topic. But I'll bite: I've worked with a lot of PHP IDEs, and the best I've ever used is PhpStorm. That's absolutely what I recommend for PHP development.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following by-pass:

Eclipse > Preferences > General > Web Browser.

Select the option for 'Use external web browser', and leave the 'Default system web browser' box ticked.